# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: beachprofile_beach.beach_id

Tags: python, html, django

I am setting up a review feature for the beach profile, and want to submit the review form in beach.html and redirect back to the original beach profile.

I am involving a addreview button and review list in beach profile but the thing is that when I open the beach profile I chose it told me that unique constraint failed for beachprofile_beach.beach_id. So I thought it's because after user reviewed it go back to the beachProfile view again and stored the same beach info into the table again. But I don't really know how to fix it.

This is a part in beachProfile view that I can store the beach info into my table Beach when I open the new beach profile page.

```
def beachProfile(request):    
    thisname = request.build_absolute_uri()
    name = thisname.split('=')[-1].replace("%20"," ")
    name2 = thisname.split('=')[-1].replace("%20","+")
    oldname = name
    #print(name  + 'hi testing')
    if oldname == '1' or oldname == '2':
        name = thisname.split('=')[2].replace("%20"," ")
        name = name.split('?')[0]
        print(name)
        name2 = thisname.split('=')[2].replace("%20","+")
        name2 = name2.split('?')[0]

    testsafe = thisname.split('=')[1]
    testsafe = int(testsafe[0])
    if testsafe == 0:
        safe=True
        halfsafe=False
    elif testsafe == 2:
        safe=False
        halfsafe=False
    else:
        safe=False
        halfsafe=True
    thisBeach = requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+name2+"&key=AIzaSyAH43dAThEg8WJge9cuFa3vbnBhLRSlJDQ")
    beachjson = thisBeach.json()
    latitude = beachjson["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
    longitude = beachjson["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]


    response = requests.get("https://api.darksky.net/forecast/fef06c56fa2906ef3255d9b99bfb02de/"+str(latitude)+","+str(longitude))
    forecast = response.json()
    windspeedcurr = forecast["currently"]["windSpeed"]
    tempcurr = forecast["currently"]["temperature"]
    uvcurr = forecast["currently"]["uvIndex"]
    summary = []
    for i in range(len(forecast["daily"]["data"])):
        summary.append("/DarkSky-icons/PNG/"+forecast["daily"]["data"][i]["icon"]+".png")

    thumbnail = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+str(latitude)+","+str(longitude)+"&zoom=14&size=400x400&key=AIzaSyAH43dAThEg8WJge9cuFa3vbnBhLRSlJDQ"
     beach = Beach.objects.filter(
        beachname=name,
        safety=testsafe,
        lat=latitude,
        lng=longitude,
        ).first()

    if beach is None:
        beach = Beach.objects.create(
            beachname=name,
            safety=testsafe,
            lat=latitude,
            lng=longitude,
        )
    is_favourite=False
    if oldname =='1':
        """
        if beach.fav.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            pass
        else:
        """
        print('adding user')
        beach.fav.add(request.user)
        is_favourite=True
    if oldname =='2':
        if beach.fav.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            beach.fav.remove(request.user)
        else:
            pass

    return render(request, 'users/beach.html', {'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude, 'summary': summary, 'thumbnail': thumbnail, 'wind': windspeedcurr, 'temp': tempcurr, 'uvindex': uvcurr, 'name': name, 'rating': 5, 'safe': safe, 'halfsafe': halfsafe, 'is_fav':is_favourite, 'safety':testsafe})
```

For my review model and review model (partial):

```
class Beach(models.Model):
    beach_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    beachname = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique = True)
    safety = models.IntegerField(default=0) #default is safe? 
    lat = models.IntegerField()
    lng = models.IntegerField()
    fav = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="fav",blank=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["beachname", "safety", "lat", "lng"]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.beachname

    def average_rating(self):
        all_ratings = map(lambda x: x.rating, self.review_set.all())
        return np.mean(all_ratings)

class Review(models.Model):
    review_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    beach = models.ForeignKey(Beach, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    user_reviewed = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="reviewer",blank=True)
......
```

The urls.py related to beach in the main is like:

```
    url(r'^beachProfile/', beach_views.beachProfile, name='beachProfile'),
    url(r'(?P<beach_id>\d+)/fav/$', beach_views.fav, name="fav"),

    url(r'^$', beach_views.review_list, name='review_list'),
    url(r'(?P<beach_id>\d+)/(?P<review_id>[0-9]+)/$', beach_views.review_detail, name='review_detail'),
    url(r'(?P<beach_id>\d+)/add_review/$', beach_views.add_review, name='add_review'),#add review to the user with same id
    url(r'^user/(?P<username>\w+)/$', beach_views.user_review_list, name='user_review_list'),
```

The code below is my code for adding a review. I don't really know how to direct back to my profile page before review so I just put the profile page link directly but excluding favorite number (fav = 1 or 2)cause I don't know how to access the fav number from the beachProfile. I really want to know how to return to the original profile page. Danger is a calculated number called safety in Beach model, and beachname is the name of the beach.

```
@login_required
def add_review(request, beach_id):
    beach = get_object_or_404(Beach, beach_id=beach_id)
    form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
        comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
        user_name = request.user.username
        review = Review()
        review.beach = beach
        review.user_name = user_name
        review.rating = rating
        review.comment = comment
        review.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        review.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        #?danger={{safety}}?name={{name}}?fav=1
        #"beachProfile?danger='+danger+'?name='+marker.title+'" is this correct way???
        return HttpResponseRedirect("beachProfile?danger='+beach.safety+'?name='+beach.beachname+'")

    return render(request, 'users/beach.html', {'beach': beach, 'form': form})
```

In beach.html, Add your review is a button to go to a form to submit user's review

```
<div id="reviews">
      <h2>Add your Review</h2>
      <form action="{% url 'add_review' beach.beach_id %}" method="post" class="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
        {% bootstrap_form form layout='inline' %}
        {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Add
        </button>
        {% endbuttons %}
      </form>
    </div>
```

I am not sure where I am wrong here, cause I am still new to learn these. Please anyone can help with resolving these error.

I am wondering the problem of IntegrityError happened is because maybe I saved any beach instance twice but I checked all my code, The only place I save instance is in beachProfile view and above you can see the code. But I don't know why it's wrong.
The error message is:

```
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, beachprofile, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying beachprofile.0007_auto_20190411_0432...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 298, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: beachprofile_beach.beach_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 309, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 274, in _remake_table
    self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 133, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 298, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: beachprofile_beach.beach_id
```

The error did not change after I change get "beach otherwise create it" to

```
beach = Beach.objects.filter(
        beachname=name,
        safety=testsafe,
        lat=latitude,
        lng=longitude,
        ).first()

    if beach is None:
        beach = Beach.objects.create(
            beachname=name,
            safety=testsafe,
            lat=latitude,
            lng=longitude,
        )
```

So I think the problem maybe is not here. I put my urls.py above. And I have other htmls: review_details.html for get the details of a review in review list, review_list.html to get a list of latest reviews, and user_review_list.html(this just add a head with user name of reviews to extends review_list) to get the details of a review in review list (you can get it by clicking the user name in a review of review list for a beach)

Also in review_detail.html:

```
<!--go back to the profile page bug here = no idea of fav number ??????-->>
<h2><a href="{% url '?danger={{review.beach.safety}}?name={{review.beach.beachname}}?fav=1' %}">{{ review.beach.beachname }}</a></h2>
```

I want to go to profile page when I click the beachname. But the redirect url maybe not that correct as well which got the same problem with add_reviews function.

Comment: Could you show your `BeachProfile` model?

Comment: I’m also not sure what this is doing `Beach(Beach.objects.get(), ...)`. It looks like you are trying to create a new `Beach` model. But you are also trying to query for a `Beach` but without anything in your get filters.

Comment: BeachProfile is not a model. That's a really long function in views.py sorry I forgot to delete the Beach.objects.get() inside Beach. I just want to create a model.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

It looks like when you are specifying your model you have a default value for your primary keys. Primary keys have to be unique. So with your `default=1` constraint, if the key isn't specified it will be set to `1`. The beauty of `AutoField` is that it will handle the setting the primary key.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#autofield

> An IntegerField that automatically increments according to available IDs. You usually won’t need to use this directly; a primary key field will automatically be added to your model if you don’t specify otherwise.

So I would recommend removing `default=1` from your Model's primary key definition

```
class Beach(models.Model):
    beach_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...,
```

Same with Review:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    review_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...,
```

---

So I’m seeing some issues with this code block if I’m understanding what you are trying to do.

```py
beach = Beach(Beach.objects.get(), beachname=name, safety=testsafe, lat=latitude, lng=longitude)
    if beach.beach_id == None and beach.beachname == None:
        beach.save()
    else:
        pass
```

When you call `beach = Beach(Beach.objects.get(), beachname=name, safety=testsafe, lat=latitude, lng=longitude)` you are creating a new `Beach` model in memory and `beach_id` won’t be set because it hasn’t been saved to your database.

It looks like you want to check if the `Beach` already exists.

You could do that with:

```py
# check if beach exists
# first will return none if no records are returned
beach = Beach.objects.filter(
    beachname=name,
    safety=testsafe,
    lat=latitude,
    lng=longitude,
).first()

if beach is None:
    beach = Beach.objects.create(
        beachname=name,
        safety=testsafe,
        lat=latitude,
        lng=longitude,
    )
```

Feel free to elaborate if I’m not understanding what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! But actually it's the main error for my program. At first I didn't add default value for both of them until I saw a post about inique contraint failed correction (perhaps). They discussed to add a default to the primary key to solve it (I don't know whether it's true, it's just in my weak memory). But main problem is still the Integrity error for the beach table.

Comment: I updated the answer with some info about how you are creating your new `Beach` models.

Comment: Have you tried removing that `default=1`? Every test that I do ends up throwing a `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint` exception. And with that line your new models' id will default to `1` unless you specify the value. Make sure after you make that change to your model you `makemigrations` and then `migrate`.

Comment: yep I deleted it. But it still got the same error. So I think it's not the problem at this step. I think it is possible to be caused by the way I write the add_review. I '''return HttpResponseRedirect("beachProfile?danger='+beach.safety+'?name='+beach.beachname+'")''' inside if form.is_valide(). And the way doing with add_to_favorite is by the hyperlink "?danger={{safety}}?name={{name}}?fav=2." Fav2 is for deletion. Fav1 is for saving. So is the problem with the redirect link?

Comment: The thing is after makemigrations and migrate. It got the same error output above.